# asp .net core razor pages - pagemodel in a layout page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I need to do some processing in a razor layout page.  The easy way to get a value from the query string is to do a Request.Query["Name"] and get the value.  previously, I had called Urldata[0] and gotten the first value.  I figured out how to overcome in this in a razor page, but I'm not having any luck trying the same thing in a layout page.  Any pointers that anyone can share?

More Info - I have a scoreboard page setup.  I can accept a tournamentid value one of two ways:
scoreboard?TournamentId=12345 or
scoreboard/12345

I need an easy way to get the tournamentid value in a layout page that accepts either format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewBag to pass data to the layout view.

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616232/7592836