# CS0103 C# The name 'ViewBag' & ''Url'' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

previously I was using vs2015. After that I installed vs2019. I opened the project in vs2019 below error appears

> CS0103 C# The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

&

> CS0103 C# The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

I tried below methods -

1. I google this error, follow that steps like clear Cache files for below path. But not happening anything.
   "%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_28331b6d\ComponentModelCache"
2. FYI link - [The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550899/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

[image]

I tried everything but same error appears.

Comment: What kind of project? (View bag implies ASP.NET, but is this core or not?) Have you ensured you have restored all package dependencies?

Comment: I am using asp.net azure project. Ya also I already check mark "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" option.

Comment: Azure could be either ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core: which (please add correct tags to the question).

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, include the actual text

Comment: Your VS2019 installation is probably missing the ASP.Net development components.  Go back and run the installer and make sure everything is installed that needs to be.

Comment: @Amy- Firstly when I run the installer, I just click ASP.NET & web development, something I missed?

Comment: I don't know, I can't see your screen. I believe this is the most likely cause of your issue, though.

Comment: I uninstall & again install vs2019, facing the same issue. If it's possible the ill share my screen.